# What HTTP Status code should I return when an internal limit has been reached?

Tags: http

Being a semantics enthusiast, I love these questions :-)

The client is attempting to create the 21st record in a collection via POST where there is a limit of 20. What is the right http status code to respond with? None seem to fit. It really isn't a 400 Bad Request, nothing is wrong in the request. 403 maybe? In the future we might support a higher limit.

Comment: 507? "insufficient storage"

Comment: In our Api, we understand this as a validation error and return 400.

Comment: But it really isn't a bad or malformed request. It's completely legit, the server just says no.

Answer (score 2):

I would use part of the `4xx client error` HTTP status codes, in special `409 Conflict`, which is defined for error in requests.

Look at [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) which describes all HTTP status codes.

Also, a `422 Unprocessable Entity` would be a good candidate, from my point of view. As you are a **semantics enthusiast**, as you're describing yourself, this code would probably better suit your needs.

Of course, this is a highly opinion-based question.

**EDIT:** [This link](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) also has a better organized reference guide about HTTP status codes.

Answer (score 0):

**429** Too Many Requests   When a request cannot be served due to the application’s rate limit having been exhausted for the resource.

**88**  Rate limit exceeded The request limit for this resource has been reached for the current rate limit window.

**403** User is over daily status update limitT Thrown when a tweet cannot be posted due to the user having no allowance remaining to post. Despite the text in the error message indicating that this error is only thrown when a daily limit is reached, this error will be thrown whenever a posting limitation has been reached. Posting allowances have roaming windows of time of unspecified duration.

Comment: I am thinking 403. It's forbidden.